# Fetch Smarty template name within php

Tags: php, smarty

I have registered a block function which takes care of translation.

$smarty->register_block("translate", "do_translation");

function do_translation ($params, $content, &$smarty, &$repeat)
{
...
}

Can i somehow determine by using the $smarty object in PHP, which template file caused the function call?
Or howelse could i fetch inside php, which template currently is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter is the Smarty object. I'm not sure, but you can try

```
echo $smarty->_current_file; //Smarty 2
```

or

```
echo $smarty->template; //Smarty 3
```

Comment: Did not work out but, finally i was able to dump the object, and i found it in $smarty->template_filepath